# Map<string, string> argument

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

I'm trying to assign a `Map<string, string>` argument to `double`. If that's even what I have to do. I have no idea how to work with this argument type. Here it is:

```
await sheet.values.map.column(3)
```

I'm using this to extract column #3 and all its values from a google sheet via gsheets. This is a nightmare to work with... Anybody know if there's another way to call the column? or if there's a way to convert the Map<string, string> to a single string containing only the values in the column ? In this case, they're coordinate values for longitude or latitude. I'm trying to call these values for plotting in Google maps. Here's the rest of my code:

```
Iterable markers = [];

var latstr = (sheet.values.map.column(3)); //latitude
var lngstr = (sheet.values.map.column(4)); //longitude

List<dynamic> names = [];
List<double> lat = [];
List<double> lng = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  names.add(latstr);
  lat.add(parse(await sheet.values.map.column(3));  //<--- I have no idea what I'm doing here. Trying to convert to double. very confused. 
  lng.add(await sheet.values.map.column(4));
}
```

to add to this, here's the full error:

> The argument type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type'double'.

here's how i'm pulling from google sheets:

```
const _spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
final gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);
final ss = await gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
var sheet = await ss.worksheetByTitle('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Comment: You must be getting an error. Could you please include that in your question?

Comment: where does the variable sheets come from? what is the type?

Comment: @neuromancer I added the info. I used the gsheet library.

Comment: @Jagraj Singh  Yes sir. Added it just now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just learned I can cut this to list string like so: await sheet.values.column(2)

Still need to be able to use this as double if possible.

Comment: @neuromancer Any idea how to make sheet.values.column(2) a double? I've tried using the parse double function with no luck.

Comment: i guess you are feeding the `parse.double` with a `Map<String,String>' that is why it is failing

Comment: I changed to double like so: double lat = [] as double;
    double lng = [] as double; However, the method 'add' isn't defined for type double. Any idea how to call the add method after converting to double?

Comment: I'm asking the wrong questions. Gsheets is incredibly frustrating to work with because it generates these goofy map string string data types and i have no idea how to convert them. i'll open a new question specifically about calling from gsheets. Thank you.

Comment: Just check out the methods in Map class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [document](https://pub.dev/documentation/gsheets/latest/gsheets/ValuesMapper/column.html) says `await sheet.values.map.column(4)` gives you a `Map<String,String>`, but `lng` is `List<double>`, so only doubles can be added to it but you are trying to asign a `Map<String,String>` which results in the error,

```
//try this to map the map into a map of doubles (mapception), if your okey with using Map instead of a list
Map<double,double> m = (await sheet.values.map.column(4)).map((key, value)=> MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
```

parse will throw if it encounters a character which is not a digit

Comment: position: LatLng(m, m2))

The argument type Map Double Double cannot be assigned to the parameter type Double :/

Comment: No it's not, it's just short code of dart that confuses

Comment: Asking in another question. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Got it. you are correct. My mistake was not adding a second parameter after m/m2:

            position: LatLng(m["test"], m2["test"])),